# Wildfly Deployment Fails at missing "jboss.deployment.unit"

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly, wildfly-10

Currently I try, for my first time, to use Wildfly with MongoDB and Hibernate OGM. When I deploy my Project to Wildfly, the following error occurs:

```
"{ \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"{MYAPP}.war\\\".STRUCTURE\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"{MYAPP}.war\\\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \\\"{MYAPP}.war\\\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0168: Error loading jboss-deployment-structure.xml from {MYUSERDIR}/wildfly10/standalone/deployments/{MYAPP}.war/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
    Message: Unexpected element '{http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee}jboss-web'\"},
\"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"{MYAPP}.war\\\".STRUCTURE\"],
\"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => undefined }"
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="ogm" services="import" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb" slot="main" services="import" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This [Jboss Document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-configuration-jbossmodule) mentions to add Modules (which I did) to the Wildfly Folder and add an Entry to the Manifest.mf File which I created manually.

Does anybody have an idea, what to try next? 
I would also appreciate a Recommendation for a good Tutorial.

Sidenotes:

- NetBeans 8.2
- Wildfly 10
- MacOS
- MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04 VM
- I googled a lot
- [The Tutorial I basically used](http://www.gregoriopalama.com/mongodb-on-wildfly-using-hibernate-ogm/)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the file that is being parsed?  It looks like the error is from a file that might look like the jboss-web.xml.

Comment: Actually, that seemed to be one Problem, I deleted the File an generated a new one. Now he claims: "org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ogm:ogm\". If I am understand this right, the jboss-deployment-datastructure File is needed to say Wildfly where to find modules, is that correct? If so, the modules are stored in "wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/" should get loaded, but Wildfly still not find them. Did I miss something?

Comment: What does your module.xml look like? It should be in the `wildfly/modules/org.hibernate/ogm/main` directory.

Comment: The important part looks like this:  
   <module-alias xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1"
    name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="main"
    target-name="org.hibernate.ogm" target-slot="5.1" />